# Binary And Continuous Data Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data

I have 37 different variables that were collected for a data set, and I'm predicting a continuous output variable. 3 of the variables are continuous so I've run independent linear regressions on all 3 to get a F(x) function, and then am working on getting weights assigned for those variables. However, I'm stumped on the binary variables. For example, one of my variables is gender, so all the men and all the women have an entire range of possible outputs between 0 and 30. I've tried doing a histogram of each binary variable and finding a logistic regression that goes atop the histogram, and then using that as my regression model upon which to apply the weighting, but I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: Any reason you’re not using a mixture of continuous and categorical predictors in your regression?

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by a mixture? I'm using both the continuous and the binary variables for the regression. Thanks!

Comment: Use a combination of them in one regression equation. What are you doing with histograms and weighting?

Comment: How would I go about to include them in the regression model? The histograms was an attempt to overlay a regression line on top of the histogram but that was clearly incorrect, I've never done statistics on binary data before.

Comment: Well how would you include 2 or 3 or 600 continuous variables in the regression equation?

Comment: At the moment each continuous variable has a 2nd degree polynomial relationship that was found. It was all thrown into excel then, and residuals were found. I did the residuals squared next, summed them, and ran solver to minimize the sum by changing the coefficients in front of each polynomial regression. I've been asked to run this all in excel for our research, so I'm not able to utilize more powerful R or python functions.

Comment: "*I've run independent linear regressions on all 3 to get a F(x) function*"; why would that marginal relationship be the same as the conditional relationship (which is what would matter for regression)?

Comment: I completely agree they aren't the same as the conditional relationship, I'm not sure where to start. A multiple regression approach will give me too few data points in each to have any meaning for example.